# Why can I unilaterally reject a suggested edit?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I recently reviewed [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/196818) suggested edit that was proposed by an anonymous user. I rejected it as I felt it offered no real improvement to the existing question, but what surprised me is that the edit was rejected overall based *only* on my review.

Is this a recent change or something that I've missed? [In the past](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/195797) a single rejection wasn't enough to reject the suggested edit. What's going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That edit was not rejected; it was approved. You cast a reject vote, after which it was still in limbo. Then two other users cast approve votes, giving it the 2 votes necessary and which resulted in an approval.

So...everything seems fine?

Comment: I genuinely have no idea how I've managed to misinterpret that - must be a Friday

Answer (score 3):

You can't unilaterally reject an edit. It was actually approved 2-1 in favor of accepting the edit.[image]

The only time you can unilaterally reject an edit is if you use the reject and edit button, then it will be rejected by community, and your edit will be put instead.

Comment: I knew about the reject end edit, seems like I've misread the outcome of the screen or something. I'll be honest, I feel like a bit of a pillock right now!

Comment: @JonK, it happens. I misread stuff a lot.